# Extract texts and colors into an array of objects / table

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

I'm trying to extract a string into an array of objects, which would contain the string itself and the color specified before it. I tried almost everything, but gmatch doesn't return the "separator", and sadly the ts-to-lua transpiler can't transform the js-style regex. (the hex value of the color inside curly brackets ({FF5050} for example))

**An example, what I'm trying to achieve:**

```lua
local text = "Welcome to thing xyz, {FF5050}username{FFFFFF}!";
local processedText = magicalTextProcessor(text);

--[[
  it should return something like this

  [
     { text: "Welcome to xyz thing, ", color: "FFFFFF" },
     { text: "username", color: "FF5050" },
     { text: "!", color: "FFFFFF" },
  ] 
]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the pattern I'd run with. Since an optional balanced operator (%b{}) doesn't exist yet I just put an if statement ahead to check for that

```lua
local text = "Welcome to thing xyz, {FF5050}username{FFFFFF}!";

if not text:match("^%b{}") then
    print("{FFFFFF}", text:match("[^%{]+"))
end

for color, text in text:gmatch("(%b{})([^%{]+)") do
    print(color, text)
end
```

[image: Output]

---

```lua
-- in a table variant
local text = "Welcome to thing xyz, {FF5050}username{FFFFFF}!";
local data = {}

if not text:match("^%b{}") then
    table.insert(data, {text = text:match("[^%{]+"), color = "FFFFFF"})
    print("FFFFFF", text:match("[^%{]+"))
end

for color, text in text:gmatch("(%b{})([^%{]+)") do
    table.insert(data, {text = text, color = color:match("%{(.+)%}")});
    print(color:match("%{(.+)%}"),text)
end

-- if you want to convert it to a json, there's a good amount of lua json libraries you can convert the table to json format
```